# Why does it say site not found after deploying?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I just set up a basic react app with firebase, and deployed it. According to the terminal, everything went fine. All that is on my index.html is a hello world. However, visiting my url still says site not found. Is there a common reason for this?

Comment: There's no way to know with the information provided.

Comment: Dave Newton what would be the best way of sharing info.. is there a way to post the code on my [git repo](https://github.com/diamonc/ichat)?

Comment: by the way, the url is https://diamonc-ichat.web.app/